# windows 7 - serial port communication, setting stop bits

Tags: windows-7, powershell, serial-port, rs232

I have a program which reads/writes to a serial port (com). I suspect that the program sets 2 stops bits for the communication (it has some problems with reading messages). I can't change a implementation so I wonder if there is any way to force (from the os level) 1 stop bit for that com port ? I have checked a device manager but it shows different port settings than the program sets.

Comment: [Configure a system device: COM / LPT port, or CMD console CON.](https://ss64.com/nt/mode.html)

Comment: When I try to check serial port parameters (mode com3) during program execution I get following message: Device COM3 is not currently available.  Is there any way to check serial port parameters in the "realtime" ?

Comment: I don't think so ... if something else is using the port you can't get at it ...